# Stack different background images horizontally?

Tags: css, background-image

I have an element on my app that needs three different backgrounds that should be stacked (?) horizontally, one following the other.

SliceA being the first of the 3, is 66px wide, then I would want to have SliceB start right after SliceA ends, and repeat-x until it stops right before SliceC starts (and this final slice has 21px—if it matters).

Right now if I do:

```
background-image: url('imgs/hint1_sliceA_66x29.png'), url('imgs/hint1_sliceB_1x29.png'), url('imgs/hint1_sliceC_21x29.png');
background-repeat: no-repeat, repeat-x, no-repeat;
```

SliceB will in fact repeat in the x axis but through the entire width of the element (note that these slices have transparency, so you can ultimately see if one of the background slices goes under another one). Anyway I naively tried this:

```
background-position: left bottom, 66px -21px bottom, right bottom;
```

But it apparently doesn't allow me to define the left and right margins of one of the background elements.

Does anyone have a workaround on how I can achieve this? Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't help you with what you've posted so far.  Can you please provide a small, self-sufficient demo showing what you've got so far - including markup (HTML) and the actual images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your images do not have any transparency then what you have will work as long as you change the orders of the backgrounds (i.e move the middle repeating background to last in the list), [example here](http://jsfiddle.net/6WbBs/). In this example the background images do have transparent backgrounds, which allow you to see the overlapping backgrounds. You may want to test this for browser compatibility, it works in Chrome and Firefox on Linux.

```
    background-image: 
        url('imgs/hint1_sliceA_66x29.png'),
        url('imgs/hint1_sliceC_66x29.png'),
        url('imgs/hint1_sliceB_66x29.png');
    background-position: left bottom, right bottom, left bottom;
    background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat, repeat-x;​
```

If this is not the case and your situation allows, it may be easiest to convert your images to ones that do not have a transparency element.

Alternatively, you could use a padding and the `background-clip` property, [example](http://jsfiddle.net/Djt9x/1/):

```
    background-clip: border-box, border-box, content-box;
    -webkit-background-clip:border-box, border-box, content-box;
    padding: 0 66px;
```

Comment: I'll give this background-clip a shot.

Comment: reading through the documentation on background-clip I remembered that one can style borders... Isn't that the way that people used to create rounded corners on buttons in the old CSS? Maybe I could use that to make this scalable? Just don't remember how it was done... :s

Comment: background-clip worked perfectly. Just had to add text-indent to make up for the added paddings and what-not...

final code:

`background-image: url('imgs/hint1_sliceA_66x29.png'), url('imgs/hint1_sliceB_1x29.png'), url('imgs/hint1_sliceC_21x29.png');
 background-position: left bottom, left bottom, right bottom;
 background-repeat: no-repeat, repeat-x, no-repeat;
 background-clip: border-box, content-box, border-box;
 -webkit-background-clip: border-box, content-box, border-box;
 padding-right: 21px;
 padding-left: 66px;
 text-indent: -45px;`

Comment: I'm glad that worked out for you. As for "the old CSS", I don't have any useful input for you. To make it scalable look into the `background-size` property.